# How to add Function App to Resource Group project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I'm working on my Azure project for gaining some experience especially in  deployment via Powershell. I already created a solution, and added an Azure Resource Group deployment project. Here you can add resources to your group, but there is no Function App, WebJobs or anything similar to Function App, or FaaS stuff.

I checked the automation script created by Azure portal about a manually created Function App, but it is quite heavy. It will take time to figure out how it works.

Is there a way to do it using this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pieces to this puzzle.

1) Is the "Infrastructure as Code" or IaC. In your case the Azure Functions PaaS Service. This can be deployed using an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template, built using Visual Studio 2017. This is the "runtime/host" that your function will be deployed to. See the [Azure Resource Group deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy) project type, part of the Azure SDK. Top tip - if you have an Azure Resource Group with a Functions PaaS instance in it, go to the instance and click on Platform Features -> Automation Template. This will give you the foundation for building your resource group deployment project.

2) Is the function itself. This needs to be deployed to your Azure Functions PaaS service. Azure functions have their own project type in Visual Studio 2017, however the template needs to be download. [See Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/)

Once you have built your function using (2) above, you publish to your function PaaS instance deployed (which was either manually deployed or deployed using (1) above).

Top Tip 2: You can build and test functions locally using the [Azure Functions CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local).

Top Tip 3: Use the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) to help understand how the ARM structure looks for your subscriptions.

Comment: For the 1, that is my problem. There is no template to create easily the "infrastructure" part of the Function App. I have to check what Azure portal does and copy it to my templates.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the case, I have added a 3rd top tip in to the answer - take a https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions